# javascript .innerhtml img doesn't display

Tags: javascript, image, innerhtml

I'm new here I've been quite struggling with this code for a few days and honestly ran out of hacks to fix it, so I'm seeking for some feedbacks...

The code bellow aims to display a validation icon for the fields properly filled in a form. The point is that the function do get the img related files but doesn't display them.

Here is the HTML :

```
<form>                
 <h6>Name</h6>
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="User name" /><span id="okname"></span><span id="not-okname"></span>
 <h6>E-mail</h6>
 <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="User email" /><span id="okemail"></span><span id="not-okemail"></span>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%; padding:0%">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  onclick="valid()" style="width:84%"/>Click here</button>              
   </div>
 </div>
</form>

<script>

    $document.ready(function("button"){
        if(valid() === true) {
            $('#name').append("img/valid-icon.png");
            $('#email').append("img/valid-icon.png");
        }
    });

</script>
```

And here is JS :

```
function valid() {

var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;
var userEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
var okname = document.getElementById("okname");
var okemail = document.getElementById("okemail");

if (userName == "User name") {
    alert ( "Please enter your name" );
    document.getElementById("not-okname").innerHTML = "<img src='../img/invalid-icon.png' />";
    valid = false;
} else if (userName == ""){
    alert ( "Please enter your name" );
    document.getElementById("not-okname").innerHTML = "<img src='../img/invalid-icon.png' />";
    valid = false;
} else if (userEmail =="User email") {
    alert ( "Please enter your email" );
    document.getElementById("not-okemail").innerHTML = "<img src='../img/invalid-icon.png' />";
    valid = false;
} else if (userEmail == ""){
    alert ( "Please enter your email" );
    document.getElementById("not-okemail").innerHTML = "<img src='../img/invalid-icon.png' />";
    valid = false;
} else {
    plus3Date();
}
};
```

Many thanks for your feedbacks.

Tom.

Comment: Please provide the problematic code there, not linking to your site.

Comment: Can you post the problem / code here please

Comment: We need some code, some html, to undestand what we are talking about. We cannot guess your javascript code ;)

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question.

Comment: Have a look at the console for your page... you can see the error there...

Comment: Please add meaningful code. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for that mistakes. I've operated the proper changes. thx a lot for your feedbacks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

    $document.ready(function("button"){
        if(valid() === true) {
            $('#name').append("img/valid-icon.png");
            $('#email').append("img/valid-icon.png");
        }
    });

</script>
```

Remove "button", the error is here in the console:

```
index.html:106 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

The document.ready function can either be written like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
     //do something here
});
```

or

According to the **jQuery** documentation, it could also be done like this:
// Passing a named function instead of an anonymous function.

```
function readyFn( jQuery ) {
    // Code to run when the document is ready.
}

$( document ).ready( readyFn );
// or:
$( window ).load( readyFn );
```

The purpose of this is to wait until the DOM is loaded, and then run the code inside. jQuery does it for you using document.ready.

Comment: Thx Zach ! Unfortunately it now return a "SyntaxError: missing formal parameter" tragetting " $document.ready(function("button"){"

Comment: Hi Zach ! Sorry for the late feedback. Above is the updated code.

Comment: You didn't remove "button" as a parameter in your document.ready function.

Comment: Actually I did ; but then console return a "missing formal parameters" error. Anyway, I made it with good old javascript as I found out something went wrong in my img urls in the js file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I had to check the URLs in my "scripts.js" file. As the js file was in parent folder of "index.html" I wrote this :

```
okname.innerHTML = "<../img src='img/valid-icon.png' />";
```

Whilst I had to write this as the URL would be written in "index.html"  :

```
okname.innerHTML = "<img src='img/valid-icon.png' />";
```

Many thanks for your helps anyway.

Cheers,
Tom.